# Why does algorithm in Tic Tac Toe game doesn't block my moves?

Tags: java

I have a working TicTacToe game, where I am trying to implement an Ai to act as player "O". The issue I'm having is that it won't block my moves. I have read through the code many times using breakpoints, but I still can't find the issue. Do any of you know what the issue could be?
This is the main minimax function:

```
public int miniMax(String player, int currentDepth, String[] board) {
    if(checkWin("O",board)){ //Checks if O wins. Returns 10-currentDepth to give value to terminal state (Ai wins)
        return 10-currentDepth;
    }
    if(checkWin("X",board)){ //checks if X wins. Returns -10-currentDepth to give value to terminal state (Ai loses)
        return -10-currentDepth;
    }
    if(checkTie(board)){ //Checks for tie. Returns 0-currentDepth
        return 0-currentDepth;
    }
    currentDepth++;//Increases depth
    if(player.equals("O")){ //If the player turn is O, I.E. the AI's turn/Max function of minimax
        bestVal=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        bestSpot=0;
        for(int i=0;i<board.length;i++){ //For loop that iterates through each possible move for O.
            if(board[i].equals(" ")){ //Checks if the spot is empty before modifying it
                board[i] = "O"; //When spot is empty, sets equal to O
                int value = miniMax("X",currentDepth,board); //Recursive part of function. Recalls function changing the current player. Once it hits an end spot, gives it terminal value
                if((value)>bestVal){ //Checks if value is better then the best, to determine best possible move.
                    bestVal = value; //If value is better, then sets new best to it.
                    bestSpot = i;// The location of the next best move
                }
                board[i]=" ";//sets the original location to empty to prevent board from being permanently changed
            }
            else{}//When the spot isn't empty, just skips that check.
        }
        return bestSpot;//Returns the best spot to allow program to make a move. This is what gets sent to gamelogic
    }
    else{ //If the player turn is X, I.E. the players turn/Mini function of minimax
        minVal=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        bestSpot=0;
        for(int i =0;i<board.length;i++){ //For loop that iterates through each possible move for X.
            if(board[i].equals(" ")){ //Checks if the spot is empty before modifying it
                board[i] = "X"; //When spot is empty, sets equal to X
                int value = miniMax("O",currentDepth,board); //Recursive part of function. Recalls function changing the current player. Once it hits an end spot, gives it terminal value
                if((value)<minVal){ //Checks if value is worse then the worst, to determine best possible move.
                    minVal = value; //If value is better, then sets new best to it.
                    bestSpot = i; //The location of the next best move
                }
                board[i] = " "; //Sets the original location to empty to prevent board from being permanently changed
            }
            else{} //When the spot isn't empty, just skips that check.
        }
        return bestSpot; //Returns the best move for X.
    }
}
```

This is my checkwin and check tie function:

```
private boolean checkWin(String player, String[] board){
    if(
            (board[0].equals(player) && board[1].equals(player) && board[2].equals(player)) ||//first col
            (board[3].equals(player) && board[4].equals(player) && board[5].equals(player)) ||//sec col
            (board[6].equals(player) && board[7].equals(player) && board[8].equals(player)) ||//third col
            (board[0].equals(player) && board[3].equals(player) && board[6].equals(player)) ||//first row
            (board[1].equals(player) && board[4].equals(player) && board[7].equals(player)) ||//second row
            (board[2].equals(player) && board[5].equals(player) && board[8].equals(player)) ||//third row
            (board[0].equals(player) && board[4].equals(player) && board[8].equals(player)) ||//diag \
            (board[2].equals(player) && board[4].equals(player) && board[6].equals(player)) //diag /
    ){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
private boolean checkTie(String[] board){
    int inter=0;
    for (String s : board) {
        if(!s.trim().isEmpty()){
            inter++;
        }
    }
    return inter == 9;
}
```

Let me know if you need any more code from the program.

Comment: Btw.: Your board should be a two dimensional array, not a one dimensional array. It is too confusing to have it as a one dimensional array.

Comment: @Progman I have the original board stored as a linked hashmap. I adapted the hashmap to an array to make it easier for coding the AI and I update the array before I call the Minimax function for the first time

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a more sophisticated reward function given a game state? I see that you only check for terminal states and there is no extra reward for "blocking" the opponent. The AI needs an incentive to perform certain moves, i.e. you need to reward it for certain actions such as blocking.